# How to count entries?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried the following code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy")
var sequenceNumber = 0
var previousPositionSize = strategy.position_size
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long, alert_message='['+str.tostring(sequenceNumber)+']')
    if strategy.position_size != previousPositionSize
        sequenceNumber := sequenceNumber + 1
        previousPositionSize := strategy.position_size
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short, alert_message='['+str.tostring(sequenceNumber)+']')
    if strategy.position_size != previousPositionSize
        sequenceNumber := sequenceNumber + 1
        previousPositionSize := strategy.position_size
```

`sequenceNumber` does not work as expected.

I would expect the sequence like: `1,2,3,4` without gaps, instead I find `1,2,2,4,4,6`. Like calculations happened concurrently.

How to properly count entries without gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in variables `strategy.opentrades` or `strategy.closedtrades` depending on your needs.

Comment: Seems extremely reliable! I wonder what I was doing wrong 

Comment: You should put this `if strategy.position_size != previousPositionSize` check in the global scope. Your entry will be executed when the bar is closed and not when your entry condition is `true`.

Comment: Ah rookie mistake, thanks